# Python Remove Comma In Dollar Amount

Tags: python, string

Using Python v2, I have the user entering an amount into a string as below:

```
RawPurchaseAmount = raw_input("Please enter purchase amount: ")

PurchaseAmount = float(RawPurchaseAmount.strip().lstrip("$"))
```

This is stripping out any blank spaces at the front of the input, and removing the $ sign if one is entered.

Is there a way to remove a comma symbol if it is entered? IE: $10,000.00 to become 10000.00

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use `replace` to remove all commas:

`"10,000.00".replace(",", "")`

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("[^\d\.]", "", "$1,000,000.01")
'1000000.01'
```

Regular expression pattern says "anything that isn't a number or a decimal point". Anything matching that regex is replaced with "".

You may need to bear in mind that some European countries use . as the thousand seperator and , as the decimal mark.

So "one million euros and 5 cents" could be €1.000.000,05 or €1,000,000.05

Comment: I like this better than my own answer. More accurate. +1.

Comment: This removes negative signs.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = '$10,00.00'
>>> ''.join(e for e in x if e.isdigit() or e == '.')
'1000.00'
```

Remove the `$`, any other character, except a digit or a `.` in one go.

Comment: This is bound to be very slow though

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
StephenPaulger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180184/python-remove-comma-in-dollar-amount/5180507#5180507) is better.

**Original Answer**

If you don't mind regular expressions you can also replace both `$` and `,` in one go. Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> RawPurchaseAmount
'$10,000'
>>> re.sub('[\$,]', '', RawPurchaseAmount)
'10000'
>>>
```

Remember to compile the regular expression if you plan to do this many times in the same program.