# Pandas data changing 500,000,000, to 5000000000

Tags: python, pandas

There are commas at the dataframe and I need to use them as integer or float but commas cause conversion to fail. What can I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Remove Comma In Dollar Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180184/python-remove-comma-in-dollar-amount)

Comment: use `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', thousands=',')`

Comment: is there any other way beacause it is not working.When I print dataset it is still 500,000