# How can I remove empty space in float from a number I get from web scraping? Error: could not convert string to float: '1\xa0364'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, precision

in the code I try to take price data from website. This website use an empty space in the price and the float class raises a flag:could not convert string to float: '1\xa0364'
this code should extract the price from the website however the empty space in the price from the website information causes an error. I am not sure if the code works or not but it does not go further to study other function.

This is actually the price: 1364, but it gives: 1\xa0364'

Please see the code:

---

```
URL = 'https://www.reebok.se/zig-kinetica-ii-edge-gore-tex/H05172.html'
headers={"user-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0'}
def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL , headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    title = soup.find( class_  = 'gl-heading gl-heading--regular gl-heading--italic name___1EbZs').get_text()
    print(title)
    price=soup.find( class_ ='gl-price-item gl-price-item--sale notranslate').get_text()
    converted_price= float(price[0:5])
```

Comment: If you only want to remove the space, you probably don't need the whole script as context, and can restructure your question to just converting a string to a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove whitespace, you can do that with things like

`split + join`

```
>>> ''.join("1\xa0364".split())
'1364'
```

`regex replace`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\s", "", "1\xa0364")
'1364'
```

You also might find this answer helpful, which basically extracts numbers and the decimal point from the string and ignores everything else:
[Python Remove Comma In Dollar Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180184/python-remove-comma-in-dollar-amount)
It might give some false positives sometimes though, e.g.

```
>>> other_option("Error: 404 file not found.  Try again in 10 seconds")
404.10
```

Comment: This is how i implemented and it works now:
   _**price=soup.find( class_ ='gl-price-item gl-price-item--sale notranslate').get_text()

    import re
    price=re.sub("\s", "", "1\xa0364")

    converted_price = float.fromhex(price[0:5])**_
I am just wondering what would happen if the price changes to a value which does not have the empty space or it is not 1364
if It is not 1364 then I should check the price online and update the value? 
My code should extract the data live, so it will raise an error if it is for instance 1 300

Comment: Is that really a hex number?  That seems shocking.  The `re.sub` solution will work fine with any number of spaces (including `0` or `100`, trailing, leading etc.)

Comment: It is not a hex number. It is a four digit number which has an empty space instead of a comma or a dot. the number is 1364. and it is written on the website as 1 364
They could probably write 1.364 or simply 1364.

Comment: `float.fromhex('10') == 16.0`.  `price[0:5]` will truncate any ints >= 100000, or anything >= 100.00. Your logic is super confusing..

Comment: I checked your solution on a different item with a different price and it actually works fine. Thank you for your solution and sorry if I am not following very well. I am very new to Python. Cheers!

Comment: Have fun learning!  Also please just do `str_price = soup.find(...)` and then `price = float(re.sub("\s", "", str_price))`

Answer (score 1):

you can use replace for this kind of things,
your code should be something like this:

```
price_str = "1\xa0364"
if len(price_str) >= 4 : # removing white space just for values with 4 or more chars
    price = float(price_str.replace(u'\xa0', u''))
else:
    price = float(price_str)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But if they change the price to lower value than 1000 then there is a shorter string and the format does not match this: "1\xa0364"
so I need a general solution to edit the number right at the float and track the price live

Comment: @Python_bug if you give me the right format for price with lower values maybe I can provide you a better answer.

Comment: That was an interesting and important point. I checked a new product and for three digit price(number) the code works and the code passes the float. Only on the four digits the website uses an empty space between the first digit and the other three. and for the four digit numbers it is always these three letters for the empty space: for instance 1052 is 1\xa052
If I understand correctly, Your solution should be valid if it is was always a fixed price, now if it changes to any other values, it till not work. 
And your code gives me 1 364 which is still not 1364

Comment: thanks for explanation; I updated my answer and fixed the extra white space.
but i think @Cireo answer is much better than mine. check it out.

Comment: Cheers mate, his answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regex to extract from script tag where already formatted for easy float conversion with "."

```
import requests, re

URL = 'https://www.reebok.se/zig-kinetica-ii-edge-gore-tex/H05172.html'
HEADERS ={"user-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0'}

def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL , headers=HEADERS)  
    name, price = [re.search(f'(?<!Brand",)"{i}":"?(.*?)[",]', page.text).group(1) for i in ['name', 'price']]
    print(f'{name}: {float(price)}')
    
check_price()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is a very interesting and working answer. and I will try this as well. however I already used Ciireo's answer on the post and it is also functional.